# Does dequeue'ing an object remove the reference from the Queue object and allow for GC?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, garbage-collection

Some backgroud:

I am looking at the various collection objects available to me in the .NET framework and trying to make a decision on which one to use.

I have to go through each object in a collection, not necessarily enumerate through them, process, and remove it. I have to do this in memory and the dataset will be large (closing in on a gig). I need my memory footprint to reduce as quickly as possible.

Question:
Does dequeue'ing an object from the Queue collection free that reference in the queue so the garbage collector can do its job? (assuming no other reference to the dequeued object)

Comment: Hopefully it should make the object eligible for garbage collection, otherwise you'd have a pretty serious memory leak :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're talking about the built-in [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) and [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) collections then **yes**, when an object is dequeued then the element in the backing array that previously held that object is set to `default(T)`/`null`, which should allow the object to be subsequently collected.

Comment: Addendum: This is *not* the case for `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, which currently leaks memory by not overwriting the element.

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes, the `Queue` class maintain an internal circular array and two variables that serve as markers for the beginning and ending of the circular array: head and tail.

The `Enqueue()` method starts by determining if there is sufficient capacity for adding the new item to the queue. If so, it merely adds the element to the circular array at the tail index, and then "increments" tail using the modulus operator to ensure that tail does not exceed the internal array's length. If, however, there is insufficient space, the array is increased by a specified growth factor. This growth factor has a default value of 2.0, thereby doubling the internal array's size, but you can optionally specify this factor in the `Queue` class's constructor.

```
The `Dequeue()` method returns the current element from the head index. 
It also sets the head index element to null and "increments" head.
```

> So the 'dequeued' object is set to
>   null and later on GCed as needed, although non-deterministic; the times when GC runs can vary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you hold no additional references to those objects, removing them will mark them for GC, though there is no guarantee when the collection will actually happen. If you have additional references, the objects will be retained in memory until those references are released.